# Assembly Language 8086 decimal fraction

Tags: cpu-registers, x86-16

How to store fraction decimal in 8086 registers? For example,

```
mov ax,0.5
mov bx,0.5
add ax,bx
```

Comment: Code formatting, correct tag

Comment: You don't. `add` instruction adds integral numbers stored in the registers, this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Registers like AX and BX can store values in the range of [0,65535].
At first this excludes numbers like 0.5 or 7.25, but you could chose a register layout that suits your needs!

You could opt to store the integer part in the high byte, and store the fraction in the low byte. Now as long as you remember this layout you can do all the usual arithmetic on these numbers.

```
mov ax, 0080h  ;integer in AH=0, fraction in AL=128 which represents 0.5 (256/2)
mov bx, 0740h  ;integer in BH=7, fraction in BL=64 which represents 0.25 (256/4)
add ax, bx
```

Now AX=07C0h which represents 7.75

Answer (score 1):

you can implement arrays that hold such point float or double float numbers,
and even calculate sine and cosine , I did such a project using that method.
basically its easiest with 2 variables of 16 bit

and just implement functions like multiplication and addition using that method
with 2 variables . or more.
this is not assembly its pseudo , just to give a glimpse of my solution

```
low_x=1000
high_x=0

divide low_x , 10000 (a div operation that stores quotient and a remainder)

add high_x,quotient
mov low_x,remainder

x=0.1
```

Comment: What the heck is `divide low_x , 10000` actually doing?  Is that integer division with the `div` instruction?  So you're doing decimal fixed-point, where you store an integer part and a `1/10k` fractional part separately, instead of floating-point or binary-fixed-point?

Comment: I made it with the div instruction of course that saves the result in 1 register and the carry at other register... I still have the full project code somewhere its a 3d cube . basically with simple math and 2 variables you could imitate floating point in 8086. tested by me, in my case i hillariously used 10,000 just because it made matter simple to me and i didn't need more than that

Comment: You mean quotient and remainder?  "carry" is a different concept, not one that applies to division of a single-word integer.  Yes, that's what `div` does; if you meant [x86 `div`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/div), write `div`.  I wondered if your `divide` was a whole function you'd written, since this was pseudocode.  Or write `mov high_x,  x/10000` / `mov low_x, x % 10000` as pseudo-code.

Comment: You are absolutely right , I will edit  the answer with these changes

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly. 8086 instruction set is very limited and do not have floating point operations. All you can do is define bytes, manipulate bytes, manipulate registers, call interrupts. This is how CPU works in level of `0` and `1`. As much as I remember from studies, we haven't done anything with floats. If you wan't floating point arithmetic, you have to implement it yourself. I can't imagine how many lines and sleepless nights it would take.